# Doing Git pull through CYGWIN

Tags: git, github, cygwin, git-shell

I was using Git shell for pulling data from GIT through (GIT pull) command.

But I am having some problems while pulling the data because of showing the message `"as file too long"`.

while creating another separate clone I get the following error message:

```
fatal: unable to checkout working tree
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
```

So can we "GIT PULL" or "GIT PUSH" through cygwin and if yes can anyone share the steps ?

Comment: Are you using Windows or Cygwin GIT client?

Comment: Are there any particularly large files in the repo?

Comment: yes there are some large files in the repo... @KeithThompson.

Comment: @AlG yes i am using Windows client..But i want to use Cygwin client..

Comment: As Adam says below before you can use Cygwin's client you have to install it and be sure it comes up in your Cygwin path first. I'd try the Cyg git client before debugging further - remove that possibility.

Comment: Just today I tried to create a large file on a FAT32 file system (a USB thumb drive). The process died when the file reached 2**32-1 bytes (2 gigabytes). Apparently FAT32 can't store files bigger than that. Are you using a FAT32 file system? (I think you should be able to convert it to NTFS.)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done. I don't know what your issue is, but I can tell you that I can use git in cygwin just fine.

1. install git in the cygwin setup installer
2. setup your git config. at a minimum, that means you'll need to open a bash prompt and type:

   1. `git config --global user.name [your name]`
   2. `git config --global user.email [your email]`
3. clone (i.e., `git clone [repo]`)

Comment: The problem was solved while installing Cywin i didnt import GIT packages.So after importing the git packages it worked.